# What are known methods of non-surgically disabling neural tracts/pathways (esp. Corpus Callosum)?

Tags: neuroscience, methods

I think I've read something about usage of TTX and optogenetics, but I cannot find the papers for either anymore. Any reference would be much appreciated, especially those concerning mice and the *Corpus Callosum*.

Edit: By *surgical*, I mean to say **methods** that are based on actually **cutting** through the tract using a surgical knife (or lasers *etcetera*), as is commonly found in literature.

Comment: Welcome to Biology. How exactly do you define *surgery*? Sticking a needle in a mouse's skull and penetrate the *corpus callosum* to inject TTX may as well be considered a surgery?

Comment: Sorry, yes this was a poor choice. By surgery I mean methods using a surgical knife to cut through the CC which is the standard method. And thanks for welcoming me :)

Comment: Can I conclude you are after *non-invasive* methods of ablating the *corpus callosum*?

Comment: Probably yes. I say probably as I have to admit that I have very limited knowledge about these things. I'm basically interested in any non-standard approach to temporarily or permanently disabling the CC (or other tracts if methods are transferable).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find one non-invasive method to sever the *corpus callosum* (callosotomy). This method is referred to as **[gamma knife radiosurgery](http://www.stlouischildrens.org/our-services/epilepsy-center/surgical-procedures/gamma-knife-radiosurgery)** [(Mathew *et al*., 2007)](http://thejns.org/doi/pdf/10.3171/ped.2007.106.4.312). Basically, 201 beams of gamma beams are focused on the *corpus callosum* and where the beams intersect, the energy is high enough to permanently damage the tissue. I doubt this technique is available for routine use in animals, though.

Another interesting technique is [**photothrombosis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_model_of_ischemic_stroke). This method is based on the systemic injection of a photosensitive dye named Rose bengal. Subsequent focal illumination of the brain with a cold light source through the intact skull leads to focal cortical infarcts of reproducible size, location and geometry [(Schroeter *et al*., 2002)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165027002000729) . Brain damage is induced due to photo-activation of the dye and subsequent endothelial damage with platelet activation and thrombosis, resulting in local blood flow interruption. The light source can be applied on the intact skull with no need of craniotomy, which allows targeting of any cortical area of interest in a reproducible and non-invasive way [(Labat-Gest & Tomasi, 2013)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3727176/). However, although the light source penetrates the skull, I don't think the method is useful for the induction of deep-brain lesions, as I was able to locate only studies using it to model cortical lesions.

Having not answered the question, I'd like to say that either surgical sectioning, or chemical ablation using micro-injection of neurotoxins are the most commonly encountered methods to perform a callosotomy.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Labat-Gest & Tomasi, *J Vis Exp* (2013); **76**: 50370](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3727176/)

**-** [Schroeter *et al*., *J Neurosci Methods* (2002); **117**(1): 43–9](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165027002000729)

**-** [Mathew *et al*., *J Neurosurgery: Pediatrics* (2007); **106**(4): 312-5](http://thejns.org/doi/pdf/10.3171/ped.2007.106.4.312)</sub>

Comment: Thanks you very much for your well researched answer. Could you maybe elaborate a on the chemical methods you mentioned at the end?

Comment: @JohnSmith - maybe that would better be done in a new question. The comments preferably shouldnt be used to ask new questions. Surgical methods were not the question. If you have questions about those you might consider posting a new one.